# At woocommerce how can the product list page open after saving/updating?

Tags: woocommerce

I was asked to change the way woocommerce acts after a product is published or updated so that the product editing page doesn't stay on but instead after pressing Publish/Update button the next page is the admin product list page (edit.php?post_type=product).

I tried the below but it doesn't work

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_product', 'on_product_save', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'on_product_save', 10, 2 );

function on_product_save( $product_id ) {
     return admin_url( "edit.php?post_type=product" );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. It triggers when a product is saved, making sure it's not an auto-save, and redirects you to the Products admin screen:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'bbloomer_redirect_to_products_after_saving_product', 9999, 3 );

function bbloomer_redirect_to_products_after_saving_product( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) || wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) || 'product' !== $post->post_type || ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! $update ) {
        return;
    }
    wp_safe_redirect( admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=product' ) );
    exit;
}
```